# Visitors are coming on the site but are not submitting questions for my Q&A site

Tags: advertising, marketing, website-promotion

Here is my site http://starsQA.com, it's purpose is that it is has stars(actors, actresses, singers, authors) and that the fans(people who like the stars) send in questions for their fav star and they get make into interviews. Currently it has 86 stars involved in the project but it is lacking questions from fans, it is getting hits(visitors) they just aren't submitting questions.

Any ideas on how to get people submitting questions???

Note: I live in New Zealand and most of the stars are in the USA (so my only contact with them is via emails) and the fans(visitors) come from all around the world, I connect with them mainly through twitter. So it would need to be a free way.

Comment: Where is your traffic coming from? Is it targeted traffic?

Comment: Mostly from twitter, youtube, facebook or google. They usually visit stars page or the index and then they seem to leave.

Comment: Landing page optimization - once your users get on the site they feel confused. Once I am confused I leave and find something less confusing, they probably do the same.

Comment: Sorry but the page for asking question just does not work. Even if it did, it is way too disconnected from the star's info.

Comment: landing page optimization noted, how so? odd ask-a-q page works my end and disconnected how so?

Comment: The combo box to select a star to ask to does not work. The drop down appears but disappears in a fraction of a second. There is no time to choose the star. Actually, using the keyboard to select works but most people use the mouse.

Comment: which browser are you using? still works right here i'm using waterfox 18.0.1

Comment: landing page optimization - I have changed the `WHAT IS YOUR QUESTION? ASK IT HERE` to a button, it is less confusing now?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to get people submitting questions???

Make it easier to do.

Your user interface is not really conducive to getting people to ask questions.  The button that is the call to action in the header uses a cramped font and is hard to read.  The site is 100% width so when I look at it on a widescreen monitor, my eye is immediately drawn to the very far left where the video (the most visually engaging object on the page) resides but from the video, my eyes are not naturally led to the call for action text which at that level is merely an all-caps bold text with the dreaded "here" anchor text.

If, for some reason, my eyes don't go far left they instead go to the top of the screen where the horizontal scrolling marquee is located.  So now I'm all the way up there where admittedly I have a better chance of seeing the button in header (save for the issues I noted initially) but unless I'm a frequent flyer on your site I have no real idea what is going on.  I would have to spend some precious time clicking about to figure out where I am and what I'm supposed to and I'm much more likely to just hit the Back button and leave at this point.

Take hints from the most popular and engaging sites on the web.  Almost all of them have a clearly marked path for the user to follow to get them engaging and interacting.

Comment: which sites would you recommend I look at?

Comment: Google, Facebook, Twitter, StackExchange, pretty much any site where visitors engage.

Comment: I have changed the `all-caps bold text with the dreaded "here" anchor text` to a button, it is less confusing now?

Comment: Well it's certainly more obvious. However, you are focusing on the trees of my answer and missing the forest. From a UI/UX perspective, your site needs lots of improvements and you may need read up a little.  Start with "Don't Make Me Think" http://www.amazon.com/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758 and see where it leads you.